# check a json array for an element and returning the full array associated with the element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json array that is always incrementing depending on the user input, here is a sample of the json code:

```
[{"scheduleid":"randomid","datestart":"2020-06-30","dateend":"2020-06-30","timestart":"08:00","timeend":"20:00","recurrences":"dailysett","daily":""},
{"scheduleid":"randomid2","datestart":"2020-06-30","dateend":"2020-06-30","timestart":"08:00","timeend":"20:00","recurrences":"dailysett","daily":""}]
```

this array is saved inside `var Schedulearray`
if i want to search for a specific id let's say i want to get `randomid` from the array by using :

```
Schedulearray.scheduleid;
```

now if the result is `randomid` i wan to get all the attribute of the element ie. timestart timeend and so on
is it possible or do i have to get each one alone like this:

```
var timestart=Schedulearray.timestart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` function:

```js
let arr = [{"scheduleid":"randomid","datestart":"2020-06-30","dateend":"2020-06-30","timestart":"08:00","timeend":"20:00","recurrences":"dailysett","daily":""},
{"scheduleid":"randomid2","datestart":"2020-06-30","dateend":"2020-06-30","timestart":"08:00","timeend":"20:00","recurrences":"dailysett","daily":""}]
var elem = arr.find((e) => e.scheduleid === "randomid");
console.log(elem);
```

Comment: This is not how [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) works, you're supposed to pass a testing function (aka a predicate), i.e. a function returning a boolean: `(e) => e.scheduleid === "randomid"`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter

```
var data=[{"scheduleid":"randomid","datestart":"2020-06-30","dateend":"2020-06-30","timestart":"08:00","timeend":"20:00","recurrences":"dailysett","daily":""},
{"scheduleid":"randomid2","datestart":"2020-06-30","dateend":"2020-06-30","timestart":"08:00","timeend":"20:00","recurrences":"dailysett","daily":""}];

var filtered=data.filter(i=>i.scheduleid==="randomid");
```